# High App Pool Memory Usage Causes ASP.net Site To Have Slow Response Time

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching, iis

We have an ASP.net MVC web application that uses a lot of memory (4GB) after it has run a few days. The server we are running it on has plenty of power to spare (CPU running about 10% and 7% memory usage), but for some reason, as the memory in the App Pool increases, the response time of the site lowers.

Even pages that are cached are taking a very long time to load. These cached pages should be served up from memory, which should be instant. We cache a lot of pages and a lot of database calls, so it doesn't surprise me that the App Pool is that big, but it doesn't make any sense to me that the more we cache, the longer it takes for the site to respond.

If I recycle the App Pool, the site is super fast again. We are using Windows 2012, IIS 8, and SQL 2012.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This seems like it would be tough to answer without access to your codebase.  Do you have you caching code centralized in some way, so you could show how you're doing it?  And do you have timed cache expiration, or any other mechanism to clear out old / unnessecarily cached things occassionally?

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are using the Mvc OutputCacheAttribute on our controller actions and Microsoft Enterprise Library Cache for our repository calls. For the most part, we never clear cache on items that won't change in the future. Are you suggesting that having a lot of old items in cache will slow the response time of the web application as a whole?

Comment: As you RAM fills up, and the same items sit in there for a long time without being accessed, the OS could be deciding to swap that data to disk (because it thinks it's safe to do so, performance-wise, since it's not going to get used). At least, I think that's how RAM works =P  So in other words, your cached data may be causing you to hit the hard drive (a slower operation).

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question but I would suggest installing something like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) on the server to try and find bottlenecks or code that is causing memory leakage.

It will give you a report of intensive functions.

You can get a pretty decent understanding of what is going wrong during the free premium trial (no card or anything needed).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will take a look at the tool. I assume it is safe to use on a production server? Have you had the problem we are encountering yourself and able to solve it?

Comment: @SwisherSweet I have encountered issues like this before yes, it's safe to run on production though it will require a restart of IIS so you will need to schedule in some downtime. We did find the rogue code that was causing the issues.